# using remove method of std::list in a loop is creating segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdlist, range-based-loop

I am using remove() of std::list to remove elements in a for loop. But it is creating segmentation fault. I am not using iterators. Program is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    list <int> li = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
    for(auto x : li)
    {
        if (x == 4) {
            li.remove(x);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In case of iterators, I understand that iterators are invalidated if we remove an element and we need to take care of incrementing iterator properly. But here I am not using iterators and I am using remove() which doesn't return any. Can any one please let me know if we can't use remove in a loop or if there is any issue with the code.

Comment: `list::remove()` removes all elements of the specified value, so in this case your `for` loop is redundant, you can just get rid of the loop altogether and use a single `li.remove(4);` statement instead since that is the only value you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But here I am not using iterators and I am using remove() which doesn't return any. Can any one please let me know if we can't use remove in a loop or if there is any issue with the code.

You are mistaken. Range-based `for` loops are based on iterators. So after this call:

```
li.remove(x);
```

The current used iterator becomes invalid.

For example, in C++17, the range-based `for` loop is defined in the following way (9.5.4 The range-based for statement):

> 1 The range-based for statement
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer ) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
>     auto __begin = begin-expr ;
>     auto __end = end-expr ;
>     for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
>         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>         statement
>     }
> }
> ```

Pay attention to that. Using the range-based `for` loop to call the member function `remove()` does not make a great sense, because the function will remove all elements with the given value.

If the compiler supports C++20, you can just write:

```
std::erase( li, 4 );
```

Comment: Suggest highlighting that `li.remove(x);` traverses the entire list and removes _all_ such elements (making the outside-for loop unnecessary).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of walking the list and removing elements alongside, what can cause invalidation of iterators, you can use the erase-remove idiom:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/qPYoxbKf6)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // remove_if
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> li = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    li.erase(
        std::remove_if(std::begin(li), std::end(li), [](int i){ return i == 4; }),
        std::end(li)
    );

    fmt::print("{}", li);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Alternatively, in C++20 there is [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase2) eg: `std::erase_if(li, [](int i){ return i == 4; });` and also [`std::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase2) eg: `std::erase(li, 4);`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it with for loop, this might be an answer.

```
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> li = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (auto iter = li.begin(); iter != li.end();)
    {
        if (*iter == 4)
            iter = li.erase(iter);
        else
            ++iter;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**erase**  returns next iterator after erase the element.
This is valid for all stl containers like vector, map, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're using iterators: a range-based `for` loop uses iterators.

See the Explanation section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Thank you. In that case, can't we use remove() inside a loop?

Comment: I'd suggest having an iterator-based loop and pre-increment before remove.

Comment: `auto itPrev = ++it;` and afterwards `if (it == 4) li.erase(itPrev);` or similar, if you wanted to reimplement `list<>::remove()`. Note that `remove()` itself removes _all_ elements of the given value, so you you could simply write `li.remove(4);` without any loop if you have the element to remove (and not a generic condition for it).

Comment: Also note, there's `remove_if()` in case you'd like to delete according to a condition.

Comment: @kadina you can't pass an iterator to `list::remove()`, you are thinking of [`list::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) instead, which also returns a new iterator to the next element, so pre-incrementing the current iterator before calling `erase()` is not necessary, eg: `for (auto it = li.begin(); it != li.end(); ) { if (*it == 4) { it = li.erase(it); } else { ++it; } }`.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements in your `std::list` are unique (as they appear in your example) or if you wish to only remove the first one, add a `break;` after your `remove` call.

The range-based-for iterator will be invalidated but inconsequentially so if never used afterwards.